# Videos not uploading with Paperclip Gem - ffmpeg in Rails

Tags: ruby, video, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, paperclip

I'm able to upload my images however, when I try to upload videos it posts as a black screen with a play button that does not work. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Do I need a video player in order for this to work?

This may be an easy solution however, I'm new to Rails. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Post Model**

```
        class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    has_attached_file :video, :styles => {:medium => { :geometry => "300x300", :format => 'flv'},:thumb => {:geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 15}
    }, :processors => [:ffmpeg] 



    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video.mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: false
    validates :video, presence: false

end
```

**AddAttachmentImageToPosts Model**

```
    class AddAttachmentVideoToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     change_table :posts do |t|
      t.attachment :video
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :posts, :video
  end
end
```

**Post _form**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :video %>
    <%= f.file_field :video %>
  </div></br>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
```

**Posts Show**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-med-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading center">
            <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
            <%= video_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4" %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= @post.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= @post.user.name if @post.user %></strong></p>

    <% if @post.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_post_path(@post) do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        Edit
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you configure ffmpeg in paperclip? I'm interested in general file uploading aspects of paperclip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184207/is-rails-paperclip-only-for-images
Maybe you could contribute your experiences back to the paperclip README.md ?

Comment: I am still unable to upload videos. I am trying to research and figure out how to get my videos uploaded. Once that is complete I will contribute however, no one seems to know the answer to my question.