# Is Rails Paperclip only for Images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activerecord, attachment

Are there any rails libraries for managing file attachments connected with ActiveRecord?

I know *paperclip*, but it seems suitable for images primarily. They indeed mention audio and pdf files on the [github project page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events), but there's no further explanation about the usage of different file types. Attributes like `:style` would change their meaning if you uploaded an audio file. So different file sizes wouldn't be expressed in a two-dimensional resolution but in terms of bitrates.

Are there any alternatives to *paperclip*? Or is it possible to not just link *imagemagick* with paperclip but for example *ffmpeg*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question above contains more than one facette. So I'll try to answer them all one-by-one.

#### *Paperclip::Processor*

It is possible to use *paperclip* for other files than images. You can define custom import actions by [subclassing *Paperclip::Processor*](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#custom-attachment-processors). The following code shows a minimal structure of a custom processor implementation. This can be adapted to any file type with custom `options`.

```
module Paperclip
  class FileContents < Processor

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      @file           = file
      @options        = options
      @instance       = attachment.instance
      @current_format = File.extname(attachment.instance.asset_file_name)
      @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
      @whiny          = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
    end

    def make
      begin

        # your import code (e.g. ocr or video resizing)...

        @file
      rescue StandardError => e
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the file contents for #{@basename} - #{e}" if @whiny
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### *paperclip* and *ffmpeg*

Someone wrote a *paperclip* processor for video files already. Have a look at the [source of paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb) gem to see how complex processors are written.

#### Alternatives

Here are some alternatives I found:

- [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
- [Dragonfly](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/)
- [attachment_fu](https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu)

Pro and Cons are already discussed [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14028826/430418).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you couldn't use Paperclip for other types of files, but if you want an alternative you can't go wrong with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).