# Is it possible to upload .mov files using Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I've been using Paperclip to save audio and pdf files to Amazon S3.  I also need to add support for .mov video files.  I don't need to play them in the browser, just save them to S3.  Is this possible?

This works for the audio and pdf files - looking for help with the .mov:

```
has_attached_file :attachment
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => [
                                    'application/mp3',
                                    'application/x-mp3',
                                    'audio/mpeg',
                                    ['audio/mpeg'],
                                    'audio/mp3',
                                    'application/pdf'],
                                     message: 'File must be of filetype .mp3 or pdf'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it possible to attach mov files you will need to add custom import action 
Exmaple is given here

[Is Rails Paperclip only for Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184207/is-rails-paperclip-only-for-images)