# 2 errors prohibited this post from being saved. Paperclip ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, paperclip

2 errors prohibited this post from being saved:

-Video content type is invalid
-Video is invalid

I'm trying to upload videos to my site locally in dev using the Paperclip Gem however, I either get a black screen with a play button that does not play the video or I get the above error message when uploading videos. I am using Rails 4.0.

Can someone please direct me in the right direction on how to get rid of this error and using the Paperclip Gem in order to successfully upload videos?

**Model**

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

    has_attached_file :video, :styles => {:mp4 => { :geometry => "300x300", :format => 'mp4' },:thumb => { :geometry => "150x150>", :format => 'jpg', :time => 5 }
        }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]



    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video/mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "video/AVI"]

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: false
    validates :video, presence: false

end
```

**Show.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-med-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading center">
            <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
            <%= video_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/MOV" %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= @post.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= @post.user.name if @post.user %></strong></p>

    <% if @post.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_post_path(@post) do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        Edit
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Migration**

```
class AddAttachmentVideoToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     change_table :posts do |t|
      t.attachment :video
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :posts, :video
  end
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :video)
end
```

**Config/enviroments/dev**

```
scout::Application.configure do

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

Here is the link to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163279/videos-not-uploading-with-paperclip-gem-ffmpeg-in-rails) regarding this one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will add my finding here hope it will help:

I noticed that you validate the image attribute for its content type and you validate video types for image.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video.MOV", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

but you don't validate the video attribute for its content type, the video also should be validated for its content type otherwise it will not work, the correct content type validation for both image and video should be as the following:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video.MOV", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that in my post model. However, now when I try to upload a video I get an error stating:2 errors prohibited this post from being saved:
Video content type is invalid
Video is invalid

Comment: @Dena what is the content type of the video you are trying to upload.

Comment: I am new to Rails so bare with me :) I believe it's MOV. When I look at the information it says IMG_1234.MOV. I added the 'paperclip-ffmpeg', '~> 1.2.0 gem' as well in hopes of getting it to work. I am running this on the dev site locally if that helps.

Comment: you should have added the 'paperclip-ffmpeg' from the beginning I thought it is already there. You also need to make sure that ffmpeg is already installed. please read and follow the requirement section literally of this [link](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thank you for that link! Apologies for not mentioning that sooner. It dawned on me while I was going through my gems. I have installed ffmpeg on my system and the gem is in place. I have restarted the server however, I am still getting the same error. Should I remove the migration and redo it? Or is there another solution. Thank you for all your help again by the way.

Comment: Paperclip must have access to ffmpeg, as per documentation in order to make sure that paperclip has access to it, on your command line, run 'which ffmpeg'. This will give you the path where ffmpeg is installed. For example, it might return /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg. Then, in your environment config file, let Paperclip know to look there by adding that directory to its path.

In development mode, you might add this line to config/environments/development.rb):

    Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

Comment: I made sure I added that in my development.rb as well when going through documentation. I still get the error. It's puzzling. Should I delete the migration and add it back? I updated my question to include all files needed.